# How to destroy a view and any models inside it using Backone

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

I have a backbone view with a model inside it. When I call the remove() on the view the events set to the model inside the removed view stay alive. I tried model.destroy() but from what I can gather this only works on the server end and not for models inside a view. or maybe I'm wrong in this.

Also when I call remove on the view I presume its just taking the views el property and calling the remove on that. If so is there a callback that you can listen for to destroy the binded events on the model inside the view.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can unbind all events on the model by calling `model.unbind()`. So you could override the `remove` method on the view like this:

```
remove: function() {
    this.model.unbind();
    Backbone.View.prototype.remove.call(this);
}
```

Actually destroying the model is a little trickier. If the model is in a collection, you might try calling `model.trigger('destroy')` before calling `.unbind()` - this will remove the model from any collections that contain it. You can then set the `view.model` to null, removing the reference from the view and hopefully freeing up the model for garbage collection. You might also call `model.clear()` to clear its fields, but this probably isn't necessary. So your full `remove` function might look like:

```
remove: function() {
    this.model.trigger('destroy');
    this.model.unbind();
    this.model = null;
    Backbone.View.prototype.remove.call(this);
}
```

Comment: The model is not part of a collection its just created inside the view when the vies is created. So does this remove function go inside the view. Also what does Backbone.View.prototype.remove.call(this);
do? is it just calling the super.remove of sorts because we are overriding the views remove method.

Comment: Ok, so calling `trigger('destroy')` is probably unnecessary. Yes, this method would go inside the view definition (as one of the options in your `.extend()` configuration), and yes, the prototype call is just a super call - see the note at the bottom of the `.extend()` docs: http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-extend

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following in the remove for your view:

```
$(this.el).unbind('.delegateEvents' + this.cid);
this.model.unbind();
Backbone.View.prototype.remove.apply(this, arguments);
```

(1) will undo any events bound during delegateEvents (the events that are keeping your view in zombie mode)

(2) will remove references between the view and the model.  You wouldn't normally remove all references like this but it's OK for you since your model is *only* for this view

(3) will call `$(this.el).remove()` as you presumed

Comment: Won't `.remove()` unbind all the view events? I don't think the first unbind call is necessary, is it?